# Trying to download Zip file using ajax but can't able to download in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Am trying to download zip file using ajax,
am returning like below from controller side. I can able to download if i use "window.location.href"
but i want to download using ajax.

Controller return code:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   zip.Save(memoryStream);
   return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", zipName);
}
```

ajax call from view side

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/zip; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (results) {
                    debugger
                    var result = results;
                    debugger
                }
            });
```

please help me to download zip file using ajax

thanks in advance

Comment: did the answer work for you?

Comment: Hey hi, am trying but am getting error in this line var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data); in ajax success. i can able to download using window.location.href but if i use that am facing some issue in other fields in that page so i want to download it using ajax. But am getting error like this "Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided."

Comment: You need to ensure you are providing data of type blob to the function you mentioned, I have updated my answer, see line before invoking 'createObjectUrl'

Comment: I tried but i's downloading empty zip file

Comment: 1. Are you sure that in your controller you are returning a stream with data that is indeed a zip file?

Comment: 2. Can you check your request in the chrome dev tools to see what data if any is being returned?

Comment: am getting error like "cannot access a closed stream" after controller method executes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214644/discussion-between-t-karalis-and-surya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1 In your controller or razor age

- a. Remove the using in your controller
- b. No need to call `.ToArray()` on the stream

```cs
public IActionResult DownloadFile(//params)
{
   var memoryStram = //wherever it is you are getting your stream from

   zip.Save(memoryStream);

   memoryStream.Position = 0; // i tend to set this if i dont know the state of the stream

   return File(memoryStream, "application/zip", zipName);
}
```

#### 2 Your ajax call

**Option 1:**
Make an ajax call and then redirect once completed to get the file

```js
function download(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/url', //call your controller and action
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", // dont forget this is required
        }).done(function () {
                //use window.location.href for redirect to download action for download the file
                window.location.href = '/api/AjaxAPI/Download';
        });
    }
```

**Option 2:** Make it all in one go

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/url',     // url to your controller/action
        method: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",           // dont forget this is required
        success: function (data) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/zip"})
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'myfile.zip';
            document.body.append(a);
            a.click();
            a.remove();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
 });
```

These are the 2 I can think of off the top of my head., i am sure there are more.